# LDAP password information update failed: Referral Not able to change password from replica

Tags: openldap

I have configured Master/Slave using slapd.conf and slurpd.

The Problem is  I am not able to change client password from slave server if Master Server is stopped.

Master Server -

```
[root@lr5dir01 ~]# service ldap stop
Stopping slapd:                                            [  OK  ]
Stopping slurpd:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@lr5dir01 ~]#
```

Slave Server -

```
[root@lr5dir02 ldap]# service ldap restart
Stopping slapd:                                            [  OK  ]
Checking configuration files for slapd:  config file testing succeeded
                                                           [  OK  ]
Starting slapd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@lr5dir02 ldap]#
```

Client -

```
[root@lr5dir02 ldap]# ssh ldaptest@10.40.109.94
ldaptest@10.40.109.94's password:
Last login: Tue Feb 19 21:14:27 2013 from lr5dir02.hk.intraxa
Could not chdir to home directory /home/ldaptest: No such file or directory
-bash-3.2$

-bash-3.2$ passwd
Changing password for user ldaptest.
Enter login(LDAP) password:
'New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
LDAP password information update failed: Referral

passwd: Permission denied
-bash-3.2$
```

Master Server - slapd.conf

```
access to attrs=shadowLastChange,userPassword
      by self write
      by * auth

access to *
      by * read

replica host=10.40.101.231:389
        binddn="cn=Manager,dc=hk,dc=intraxa"
        credentials=secret
        bindmethod=simple
        tls=no
```

Slave Server slapd.conf - same as Master only

```
updatedn "cn=Manager,dc=hk,dc=intraxa"
updateref ldap://10.40.101.230:389/
```

Client Pam -

```
[root@lr6tst01 ~]# more /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth

[root@lr6tst01 ~]#


Log - Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: read active on 14
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=4 BIND dn="uid=ldaptest,ou=People,dc=hk,dc=intraxa" method=128
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=4 BIND dn="uid=ldaptest,ou=People,dc=hk,dc=intraxa" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=4 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:  14r
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: read active on 14
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=5 MOD dn="uid=ldaptest,ou=People,dc=hk,dc=intraxa"
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=5 MOD attr=userPassword
Feb 19 21:43:54 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=5 RESULT tag=103 err=10 text=
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:  14r
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: read active on 14
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: connection_read(14): input error=-2 id=2, closing.
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 op=6 UNBIND
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: removing 14
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: conn=2 fd=14 closed
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: activity on:
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]:
Feb 19 21:43:56 lr5dir02 slapd[7147]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `slurpd`, you must be using an old version OpenLDAP -- the supported replication configuration is strictly single-master (RW), with read-only replica nodes. `slurpd` is no longer supported, partly because it can only support this mode.

What's happening is the read-only node knows it cannot accept a write request (other than from the master), so it is giving a *referral* to the client, sending to the writeable node (i.e. to the `updateref` URI in your configuration).

You should upgrade to OpenLDAP 2.4, and use the *syncrepl* protocol for replication. This allows three replication scenarios:

1. single RW master, multiple RO replica nodes
2. full multi-master RW (with some caveats)
3. *mirrormode* hybrid (active hot-standby), using balancer or proxy

You can use syncrepl with OpenLDAP 2.3, but I strongly recommend upgrading (or you might be missing out on up 5 years of enhancements and patches to syncrepl, depending on what packages you're using and whether any fixes have been back-ported).

The only option with your current set up is to manually alter the configuration of a RO node to promote it to master when the master goes offline, as you can guess this can be problematic to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Spuratic , yes I am also thinking to upgarde to syncrepl , actually I got this project for another team and they wanted simple LDAP using slapd.conf/slurpd for authentication purpose only. Thanks again. Can I use syncrepl with slapd.conf where I dont want cn=config configuration. Is it possible to use syncrepl with slapd.conf configuration.